# How to run code and do data analysis in mathematica

Tags: import, data

I am a beginner in Mathematica. I'd like to do something like the following:
[image]

write code- ouput- write code- output...

But when I created my own notebook and copy the code above, I don't know how to run them. Shall I download another Wolfram software or what should I do? Thanks a lot.

By the way, I see an orange equal sign on the left each time.

Comment: You need to evaluate the cells. Press "Shift+Enter" to run the current cell, or   you can use any of the other commands under "Evaluation".

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the cells. You can evaluate the current cell by using "Shift+Enter".

For an introduction to evaluation, here are some helpful references:

1. [Interactive Usage page](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/interactive-usage/) of *The Wolfram Language: Fast Introduction for Programmers*.
2. [Practicalities of using the Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/practicalities-of-using-the-wolfram-language.html) from *An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language* by Stephen Wolfram